# Best way to secure Wi-Fi Direct connection

Tags: wifi, android

I have setup WiFi Direct connection between two Android devices by using Wi-Fi Protected Setup (WPS) "push button" for authentication.I also want to secure the connection itself by securing the data transmission between any two peers.

**Edit:** The WiFi Direct standard says to support WPA2 ciphering, but I'm not sure how it works (there is no way to configure the passphrase of it), and if it works at all.

One way of doing this could be to make some cipher key that the two peers shares and encrypt all the traffic coming out of specific port that I'm using.

Can you suggest some other method to make the connection secure?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html#getPassphrase%28%29 see http://security.stackexchange.com/a/26345/31943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods, which depend on where you want to use it for.

You should use WPA2 (with a pass-phrase), which is the standard for wireless network security. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup) WPS generates the passphrase from the 8 digit PIN code and is vurnable to brute-force.

It is also possible to have security at application level. For various types of traffic, you can use an SSL layer. SSL is most commonly used in https.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is do not use WPS as it is vulnerable to the [reaver](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/) attack.

This greatly reduces the amount of time needed to bruteforce your passpharse.

Comment: The WPS method is the one with a "push button" and not passphrase, which make the vulnerability that found in 2011 irrelevant. But I'm not asking about the authentication security, I'm asking about the communication data that the peers send after the authentication already done.