# How to secure Wifi Direct p2p connection between android devices?

Tags: wifi, android

I found [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26279/192824) answer. However, I want to know how to use WPA2 and ssl to secure wifi - direct connection.

Also is there a way to make wifiDevice visible only in the app that I want and not in other wifi-direct apps that may look for all devices using searchPeers.